# The error "Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 429" in web scraping in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I got the code from youtube. The coder indicated that it is working. I copied it, but it did not work on my PC.

The code below produces the error  `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 429.`

I also could install `library(DataExplorer)` on my PC. I tried `install.packages("DataExplorer")` and this

`if (!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools") devtools::install_github("boxuancui/DataExplorer")`
and this

`if (!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools") devtools::install_github("boxuancui/DataExplorer", ref = "develop")`.

None of them worked. I am wondering if the error message has anything to do with package. If not, what causes this and how to fix it?

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(DataExplorer)
library(stringr)

url <- 'https://www.sahibinden.com/audi?query_text_mf=audi&query_text=audi'
html <- read_html(url)
View(html)
nodes <- html %>% html_nodes('.mtmdef') %>% html_text()
nodes
num_of_nodes <- regmatches(nodes, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+",nodes))
num_of_nodes <- as.numeric(unlist(num_of_nodes))
nodes_sub_1 <- html %>% html_nodes('.mbdef') %>% html_text()
nodes_sub_1
nodes_sub_1 <- html %>% html_nodes('.currentPage') %>% html_text()
nodes_sub_1

list_of_pages <- str_c(url, '?pagingOffset=', seq(0,980,20))
list_of_pages <- if_else(
str_detect(list_of_pages, "pagingOffset=0") == TRUE,
"https://www.sahibinden.com/audi?query_text_mf=audi&query_text=audi", 
list_of_pages
)
list_of_pages

ilanlar <- html %>% html_nodes("#searchResultsTable") %>% html_table(fill=TRUE)
ilanlar <- as.data.frame(ilanlar)[-1]

ilanlar

get_tables <- function(html_df){
as.data.frame(
read_html(html_df) %>% 
  html_nodes("#searchResultsTable") %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE) 
 )
}

data <- list_of_pages %>%
map(get_tables) %>%
bind_rows()
```

The last part produces the error message.

Comment: Where does the error occur? Here  `html <- read_html(url)`   ? Or when you tried to run the install line? Or somewhere else?

Comment: `data <- list_of_pages %>%
map(get_tables) %>%
bind_rows()`